# Adafruit Fona establishes connection with echo server, but doesn't send over any data

Tags: c++, stm32, gsm, mbed, adafruit

Using mbed OS and stm32 nucleo board with Adafruit Fona 3g, I am trying to send data to a server via 3g connection. I am using the .cpp file and .h file posted here: https://os.mbed.com/users/Nels885/code/Adafruit_FONA_3G/file/b18cfba4283a/

The code seems to get stuck on getTCPtimeout. I am having trouble figuring out why this is the case.

I have tried commenting out the getTCPtimeout function to see the results and the code runs through completely, but never establishes a connection with the server.

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Adafruit_FONA.h"

#define FONA_RST D4
#define FONA_TX D1
#define FONA_RX D0
#define FONA_RI D7 //not used

char replybuffer[255];


Adafruit_FONA_3G fona(FONA_TX, FONA_RX, FONA_RST, FONA_RI);
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

int main() 
{

    fona.TCPinitialize();
    pc.printf ("initialize \n");
    char *Timeout = "10000000";
    fona.getTCPtimeout(Timeout);
    pc.printf ("timeout \n");
    char * Server = "47.218.188.133";
    uint16_t Port = 23;
    fona.TCPconnect(Server,Port);
    pc.printf ("connect \n");
    char * Packet = "Pick Up %";
    fona.TCPsend(Packet);
    pc.printf ("send \n");
    fona.TCPclose();
    pc.printf ("close \n");
    }
```

Edit: I was running the code and noticed that after fixing the above issue, the code would get stuck TCPSend function, specifically right before 
    packet[0] = 0;
which is shown down here:

```
bool Adafruit_FONA_3G::TCPsend(char *packet)
{
    if (strlen(packet) > 0) {
        mySerial.printf("%s", packet);
        //mySerial.printf("%s\r\n", packet);

        readline();

        packet[0] = 0;

        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

When commenting out the line, the code would run all the way through. I am still in the process of testing to see if the code still functions as intended, but my question is what exactly is the purpose of packet[0] = 0;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Adafruit_FONA_3G::getTCPtimeout()` assumes that you pass it a writable buffer of size > 20.  You're passing a read-only buffer of smaller size.  So, replace

```
char *Timeout = "10000000";
```

with

```
char Timeout[21];
```